# Relationship field in channel form

Tags: relationships, channel-form

I'm trying to create a way to edit a relationship field on the frontend via the channel form (the new safecracker name). The field appears well, but the search function at the top with the little magnifier doesn't work. It doesn't filter the entries.... Has someone been able to have that working?

I have tried with a playa field too and it works.

Here is a simplified code. Did I miss something?

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
{exp:channel:form channel="events" return="events/thanks" entry_id="2" }
    <input name="title" type="text" value="{title}">
    {field:persons}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of EE?

Comment: Check you browser console... There are probably JS errors that will help you track this down.

Comment: Was there ever a solution found for this question?